# How can DateObject handle calender weeks

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, conversion

I have dates given for a `TimeLinePlot`. These dates are in `{year,week}` format.

`DateObject` does not take this with `DateObject[{2014,26},DateFormat->{"Year","Week"}]`. `DateFormat` should handle `DateString` format. There the week is given as option.

Does anyone have an idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `DateList` to work out the date.  For example, (naïvely assuming week 1 begins on January 1st).

```
{year, week} = {2014, 26};

date = DateList[{year, 1, (week - 1)*7 + 1}]
```

> {2014, 6, 25, 0, 0, 0.}

For example:

```
dates = {{2014, 2}, {2014, 8}, {2014, 16}, {2014, 26}};
values = {4, 6, 3, 8};
newdates = DateList[{#1, 1, (#2 - 1)*7 + 1}] & @@@ dates;
DateListPlot[Transpose[{newdates, values}]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Using [ISO weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) and adjusting accordingly.  (ISO week is taken to be "*the week with the year's first Thursday in it* ", so week 1 of 2014 begins on December 30th 2013.)

[image]

```
isodate[{year_, week_}] := Module[{isoAdjust },
  isoAdjust = Cases[Map[{#, DateString[{year, 1, #},
          "DayNameShort"]} &, Range[7]], {_, "Thu"}][[1, 1]] - 3;
  DateList[{year, 1, (week - 1)*7 + isoAdjust}]]

isodate[{2014, 1}]
```

> {2013, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0.}

```
isodate[{2014, 26}]
```

> {2014, 6, 23, 0, 0, 0.}

```
newdates = isodate /@ dates;
DateListPlot[Transpose[{newdates, values}]]
```

Comment: Just one comment for sake of clarity. The US does not ISO weeks. They use first Saturday to start the week numbering. Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 5):

**Note** This answer exposed a bug in `DateList`'s handling of the `"Week"` (or `"WeekShort"`) element for week one when it begins in the previous year.  This was spotted by @ChrisDegnen (see the comments) and has been acknowledged by Wolfram who suggested the workaround.

---

I don't believe `DateObject` has a concept of a week as a period of time in the same way that it seems to for a year, month or day, so I think the best you can do is a `DateObject` for the first day of the week.

And since the `DateFormat` option for `DateObject` is the display format rather than an interpretation format we use `DateList` to do the conversion...

```
fromYearWeek[{y_Integer, w_Integer}] := 
 DateObject[
  DatePlus[DateList[{ToString[y] <> "-" <> ToString[w], {"Year", 
      "Week"}}], 1], DateFormat -> {"ISOWeekDate"}]
fromYearWeek[{y_Integer, 1}] := 
 DateObject[
  DatePlus[DateList[{ToString[y] <> "-2", {"Year", 
      "Week"}}], -6], DateFormat -> {"ISOWeekDate"}]
```

Note that I have added a day to convert to ISO weeks which begin on a Monday and changed the `DateObject` display format to indicate the week number.

It includes a special case for week one - calculating the date list for week two and subtracting 6 days.

Comment: Interesting about [ISO weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) but the code is wrong: `DateList[{"2014 1", {"Year", "WeekShort"}}]` produces `{2014, 12, 29, 0, 0, 0.}` - miles out. Consequently `fromYearWeek[{2014, 1}]` produces `2015-W01-2 GMT`.

Comment: from `YearWeek[{2014, 2}]` gives `2014-W02-2 GMT` which is okay. But I did not find the reason yet. Spezifiying that a `DatePlus[...,{1,"Day"}]` should add a day does not help.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen my non-extensive testing did not spot that slight problem! I guess this is something to do with week 1 containing the first Thursday so I guess your custom solution is better.

Comment: It looks like a Mathematica bug.  `DateList[{"2014 1", {"Year", "WeekShort"}}]` is stepping back but not decrementing the year, so it finds Monday in December but for 2014, not 2013.  Same problem happens for `DateList[{"2013 1", {"Year", "WeekShort"}}]`.  However `DateList[{"2015 1", {"Year", "WeekShort"}}]` is correct : `{2014, 12, 29, 0, 0, 0.}` - perhaps because Jan 1st 2015 is a Thursday.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Agreed. I'll report this to Wolfram support.

Comment: That is great. Otherwise I would have done it.